# How come Heimdall seemed to have grown dreadlocks between The Dark World and Ragnarok?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-ragnarok, thor-the-dark-world

In *Thor: The Dark World*, Heimdall looks bald, maybe because he is wearing a helmet throughout the film, but in *Thor: Ragnarok* he has long dreadlocks.

Where did his hair come from? Did he have hair in *The Dark World*?

Comment: I think you just answered your own question.

Comment: https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/disney/images/d/dd/Thor_The_Dark_World_Heimdall.png/revision/latest?cb=20130926202936 he's got hair right there in the screenshot. it's short, but he's not bald.

Answer (score 11):

### He is not bald.

As guardian of the BiFrost, he appeared to keep his hair short to accommodate his helmet.

With helmet:

[image: Close up of Heimdall, he wears his golden coloured armour over chain mail with leather wrapped arms; the breastplate depicts the World Tree; he has a beard and moustache and is shown with the large ornate helmet on]

Without:

[image: A side view of Heimdall moments after the previous image after removing his helmet; he has buzz cut short hair but hair is there]

We can safely surmise that after he abandoned his post (because of Loki impersonating Odin) and he lived away from the city, he let his hair grow out.

[image: Close up of Heimdall's face; his sword can be seen on his back; he's wearing an outfit consisting of rags; his beard is longer and greyer as is his hair which is now in dreadlocks]

*Side note:* In Thor's vision of Ragnarok (*Age of Ultron*), his hair is still short.